# Scope of SQL query in multiple instances of a form

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-xe3

I have a form that I open multiple instances of. In there I use a SQL query to read some data from a database (Absolute Database in this case). I then fill out a few variables with data and also use the query for other operations during the lifetime of the form.

The problem is that when I open more than one instance of the form, the data change on the old forms to values from the last opened form.

I create the query in the form when it's opened so I thought that they wouldn't share the same data.

I don't use auto-created forms.

How can avoid this from happening?

** Edit - Added some code **

I create the form as follows:

```
procedure TfrmMain.OpenFormsFunction(Sender: TObject);
var
  Resultater:   TfrmregResultat;
begin
// Some code for checking if forms are already open
// Locate record in table to be used as paramdata in the query in the newly opened form
DataX.tStevneHead.Locate('StevneNummer;GrenType', VarArrayOf([StevneNummer, GrenType), []);
Resultater := TfrmRegResultat.Create(nil);
Resultater.Show; // OnClose action for the form is caFree
end;
```

Snip from the form's code

```
// decleared in implementation
Dato:        TDate;
GrenType:    string;
GrenRunder:  integer;
MaxPoeng:    integer;

procedure TfrmRegResultat.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
//-- qStevneHead is a TABSQuery component on the form
//-- DataX is the name of my DataModule
with qStevneHead do
begin
  Close;
  SQL.Clear;
  SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM StevneHead WHERE GrenType = :aGrenType AND StevneNummer =  aStevneNummer';
  ParamByName('aGrenType').AsString := DataX.tStevneHead.FieldByName('GrenType').Value;
  ParamByName('aStevneNummer').AsString := DataX.tStevneHead.FieldByName('StevneNummer').Value;
  Open;
end;
GrenRunder := qStevneHead.FieldByName('AntallRunder').Value;
Dato := qStevneHead.FieldByName('Dato').AsDateTime;
GrenType := qStevneHead.FieldByName('GrenType').Value;
MaxPoeng := qStevneHead.FieldByName('MaxPoeng').Value;
// More code to init stringgrid and other stuff on the form
end;
```

Comment: If I get it right, you change some data in form A and close it (for instance). Then you switch to another, already opened form B which displays the data you've changed in form A, but since you've loaded the data when you've created the form, the data are not actual anymore. Is that right ?

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem might be; this definitely isn't normal. Can you [edit] to include the code that creates the query and the code that creates the instances of the form?

Comment: Yes, it is impossible to answer this without seeing the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for looking in to it for me. Added some code. It works fine as long as there is only one form open, but when I open a second, Grentype and others changes to the value from the new form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're using global variables. Change them to be fields of the form and your problem should be solved. IOW, now you have

```
implementation

var
  Dato:        TDate;
  GrenType:    string;
  GrenRunder:  integer;
  MaxPoeng:    integer;
```

Change it to

```
type
  TfrmRegResultat = class(...)
  ...
  private
    Dato:        TDate;
    GrenType:    string;
    GrenRunder:  integer;
    MaxPoeng:    integer;
   ...
  end;
```

If you need to access the values from some other part of the program (ie in the main form) then make them public propertyes or fields and access them via the currently active form variable.